# How to avoid NULL check in JOIN condition in Tableau

Tags: druid, tableau-desktop

I am trying to change backend DB for Tableau dashboard. Tableau is generating JOIN SQLs with conditions such as:
`ON a.col1 = b.col2 OR (a.col1 is null and b.col2 is null)`
Is there a way we can avoid having `OR (a.col1 is null and b.col2 is null)` condition? I tried ZN and IFNULL with the column name but still such conditions are getting added. The Druid DB supports JOIN only with equality condition and because of IS NULL check , the query is failing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tableau is treating NULL as if it were a value and in SQL that is not the case, it is the absence of a value. According to
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/joining_tables.htm in the section named "About null values in join keys" it mentions an option to set "Join null values to null values", perhaps that is turned on in your case.

On the Druid side if you want to treat NULL as meaning a default value, then a possible route is to transform the NULL into a special value (say -1 or whatever is out of the normal range of the values) and have that value exist on both tables instead of NULL.

In Druid at ingestion time you can use:

```
   ...
   "transformSpec": {
        "transforms": [
          {
            "type": "expression",
            "name": "col1",
            "expression": "nvl( col1, -1)"
          }
        ]
   ...
```

which will replace `col1` with the calculated column `col1` ( this is called shadowing) that has replaced `NULL` values with `-1`.

for more info on the `transformSpec` and on expression functions that are available you can go to:

- https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html#general-functions
- https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/ingestion/ingestion-spec.html#transformspec

Answer (score 0):

Please note that setting the join type in Tableau as « many to many » solves the issue and removes the extra join for null handling.